# How to select option from a dropdown using python - selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to automate data downloading process by using python and selenium combination.
and got stuck in selecting options from a dropdown.
here is the element in the page i am trying to interact with.

when a option is already selected here is the page  element looks like.

```
<div id="market-dashboard-categories" class="dash-dropdown"><div class="Select mt-1 mb-2 ibm-font-400 has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single"><div class="Select-control"><div class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-17--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-17--value-item">ABB: All Bedrooms (56071 listings)</span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input autocomplete="off" aria-activedescendant="react-select-17--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 12px; font-family: &quot;IBM Plex Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></div><span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value"><span class="Select-clear">×</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></div>
```

when no options selected the code looks like this

```
<div id="market-dashboard-categories" class="dash-dropdown"><div class="Select mt-1 mb-2 ibm-font-400 is-clearable is-searchable Select--single"><div class="Select-control"><div class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-17--value"><div class="Select-placeholder">Select..</div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input autocomplete="off" aria-activedescendant="react-select-17--option-0" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 12px; font-family: &quot;IBM Plex Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></div><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></div>
```

Some methods that I have tried

1. when i am Sending keys (group name) to this element `<div class="Select-placeholder">Select..</div>`.but this is not working
2. sending keys to this element

```
<div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input autocomplete="off" aria-activedescendant="react-select-17--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 12px; font-family: &quot;IBM Plex Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
```

also not working.

When I am hovering onto options this element `react-select-17--option-0` changes from `option-0` to `45` but I am not able to click on those option as well.

the code that i wrote.

```
    # Switch to the iframe
    iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "report-iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    # Click inside the box to open the dropdown
    box = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="market-dashboard-categories"]'))
    )
    box.click()
    print("Box clicked.")

    # Clear the placeholder
    clear_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="market-dashboard-categories"]/div/div/span[1]'))
    )
    clear_button.click()
    print("Placeholder cleared.")

    # Click on the input element again to open the dropdown
    box.click()
    print("Dropdown opened again.")
    time.sleep(5)  # Adding a small delay to ensure the dropdown is fully loaded

    input_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-select-17--value"]/div[1]/input'))
    )
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
    print("First option selected.")
```

But i am not able to select a option from dropdown by this code.

Comment: Can you share a link to the page? It would help a lot. Most likely, you are going to need to click the dropdown element to open it, then click one of the exposed elements in the dropdown options. We can't help with that without more of the HTML of the page.

Comment: Hi JeffC ,
thanks for the help but the page require user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Run this lines:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

items = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'market-dashboard-categories'))

items_list = []
for item in items.options:
    items_list.append(item.text)
    print(item.text)
```

If everything was OK, you can select items by this, for example first item:

```
items.select_by_visible_text(items_list[0])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but there are no list on the page to select , its all coming dynamically , just when i am hovering on to dropdown option react-select-17--option-0 this option-0 changing and once i click on to option the above changes to this react-select-17--value and other changes in the page i have mentioned in the question.